# Character formula for $U(N)$ with $ \{ \lambda \} = l_1 \geq l_2 \geq \dots 0\geq \dots -m_1 \geq \dots \geq -m_q$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

In the appendix of https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(81)90486-7* there is a formula given for the character for an irreducible representation $\{ \lambda \} $of $U(N)$ as follows (equation A.17 on page 145):

\begin{equation}
\chi_{l_1l_2\dots l_p ; m_1m_2\dots m_q} = (-1)^{pq}\det(\overline{M})
\end{equation}
where for $ i=1,\dots p$
\begin{equation}
\overline{M}_{ij} = \begin{cases} W_{l_i + j-i -q} \quad  l_i + j-i -q \geq 0\\
0 \quad  l_i + j-i -q < 0\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and $ i=p+1,\dots, p+q$
\begin{equation}
\overline{M}_{ij} = \begin{cases} W^*_{m_{i-p} -j+i-p} \quad  m_{i-p} -j+i-p \geq 0\\
0 \quad  m_{i-p} -j+i-p < 0\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
W_n(U) := \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{Tr}^\sigma(U)
\end{equation}
and finally
\begin{equation}
\{ \lambda \} = l_1 \geq l_2 \geq \dots 0\geq \dots -m_1 \geq \dots \geq -m_q
\end{equation}

I have seen many times Weyl's character formula and variations of that, but only for the case where $\{ \lambda\} = \lambda_1 \geq \dots \lambda_n \geq 0$. This is the first time, that I encounter this formula and in the paper they do not cite it nor derive it. I don't know if it a trivial generalisation that needs no explanation of something I have not comprehended yet. Is there any derivation for this formula, that goes deeper than the authors that I cited ?

"CHIRAL MODELS: THEIR IMPLICATION FOR GAUGE THEORIES AND LARGE N (Frederic GREEN and Stuart SAMUEL)"

Comment: [Itzykson, C. and Nauenberg, M., 1966](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/pdf/10.1103/RevModPhys.38.95). Unitary groups: Representations and decompositions. Reviews of Modern Physics, 38(1), p.95. Appendices of physics papers are a terrible place to learn group theory from.

Comment: Thank you, there they talk about contragradient representations (which I believe plays a role in the derivation), but still don't mention the above formula.