# Is $\text{Tr}(U^{-1}) = \frac{1}{2} (\text{Tr}(U) ^2 - \text{Tr}(U^2))$ for $U \in SU(3) $?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, physics

Is it true that $\text{Tr}(U^\dagger) = \frac{1}{2} (\text{Tr}(U) ^2 - \text{Tr}(U^2))$ for $U \in SU(3) $ ? In particular are there more general formulas/ systematic way of reducing higher powers of traces to expressions involving the complex conjugate of the trace ?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: in my previous question [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4489216/character-formula-for-un-with-lambda-l-1-geq-l-2-geq-dots-0-ge)  there is a formula for calculating characters, from which as a byproduct the statement in question could follow...

Comment: notice that $U$ is normal, so you can consider it diagonal. Now you can write the traces as function of three norm 1 variables whose product is 1

Comment: Okay thanks! Is there any more general theorem, other than the one I linked in my comment, that gives systematic reductions of that sort ?

Comment: It suffices to observe that if $U$ has eigenvalues $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$, then $\alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_3=\det(U)=1$ and $|\alpha_i|=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem#Determinant_and_inverse_matrix), for any 3×3 matrix, not just a unimodular one,
$$
A^3- (\operatorname{tr}A)A^2+\frac{1}{2}\left((\operatorname{tr}A)^2-\operatorname{tr}(A^2)\right)A-\det(A)I_3=O,\leadsto \\
A^{-1} \det(A)=  A^2- (\operatorname{tr}A)A+\frac{1}{2}\left((\operatorname{tr}A)^2-\operatorname{tr}(A^2)\right) I_3.
 $$
so taking the trace for a unimodular matrix yields your formula.

You get the extension for generic *n*.